# LSTM array conversion

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, lstm

I am writing a function to extract features of a url passed on and return that as a list

```
def main(url):
    
    status = []
    
    status.append(having_ip_address(url))
    status.append(abnormal_url(url))
    status.append(count_dot(url))
    status.append(count_www(url))
    status.append(count_atrate(url))
    status.append(no_of_dir(url))
    status.append(no_of_embed(url))
    
    status.append(shortening_service(url))
    status.append(count_http(url))
    status.append(count_https(url))

    
    status.append(count_per(url))
    status.append(count_ques(url))
    status.append(count_hyphen(url))
    status.append(count_equal(url))
    
    status.append(url_length(url))
    status.append(hostname_length(url))
    status.append(suspicious_words(url))
    status.append(digit_count(url))
    status.append(letter_count(url))
    status.append(fd_length(url))
    tld = get_tld(url,fail_silently=True)
      
    status.append(tld_length(tld))
    
    
    

    return status
```

Now I am using this 21 features in my LSTM model to predict it's output

```
def get_prediction_from_url(test_url):
    features_test = main(test_url)
    features_test = np.array(features_test).reshape(features_test, [1, 1, 21])
    print(features_test)

    

    pred = model.predict(features_test)
    if int(pred[0]) == 0:
        
        res="SAFE"
        return res
    elif int(pred[0]) == 2.0:
        
        res="MALWARE"
        return res
    elif int(pred[0]) == 1.0:
        res="PHISHING"
        return res
```

but it is giving an error on features_test = np.array line that "'list' object cannot be interpreted as an integer"

i was expecting for the array to be converted into an array for lstm model but the array converseion is giving me issues, i have total 21 features

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).